# Comportamiento raro de Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en sql, cuando lo ejecuto en el mismo sql corre todo Ok:

```
declare @x as varchar(13)
exec sp_nuevo_codigo 'AGB', ''
print @x
go
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto desde C#, vb, Fox Arroja este error:

- en el Profiler:

  ```
  declare @p4 varchar(8000)
  set @p4=''
  exec sp_executesql N'exec sp_nuevo_codigo @P1  @P2 OUTPUT ',N'@P1 varchar(3),@P2 varchar(8000) OUTPUT','AGB',@p4 output
  select @p4
  ```
- El error:

  > ```
  > Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
  > Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@P2'.
  > (1 row(s) affected)
  > ```

Comment: No uses negrita `**` para el codigo. Puedes usar backtick "`" para nombres de variables o usar 4 espacios antes de cada linea para bloques. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de utilizar desde c# un sqlCommand con los parametros bien definidos:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_nuevo_codigo", conexionOK))
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@P1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor1.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@P2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor2.Text;

  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```